Typing remotely in Dameware not working as expected
Sometimes I need to use Dameware to access some computers remotely. To communicate with the other person, I open Notepad and type, but I noticed that when I use accent marks, I have to press the letter twice to apply the accent.
Additionally, some special characters don't appear at all when I try to type them, like ç, ª, º…
I'm using the version 6.8.1.4 and a Portuguese Qwerty (Portugal) keyboard.

What is your keyboard? Is it US qwerty? Have you check the keyboard of target machine, maybe it is UK qwerty?

I'm from Portugal and only access remotely to portuguese keyboards, using a portuguese one too. Portuguese Qwerty (Portugal)
